# Como armazenar mais de um valor usando SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sharedpreferences

Estou fazendo um app onde criei um checkbox para representar um o item favorito.

O problema que estou tendo é que estou tendo é quando coloco mais de um item como favorito, o último substitui o primeiro, ou seja, está permitindo adicionar somente um registro.

Como posso salvar vários registros usando sharedPreferences?

Segue meu código:

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
// EVENTO DE CLIQUE
           lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                   // CHECK BOX
                   View checkBoxView = View.inflate(FraseAutorFrase.this, R.layout.checkbox, null);
                   CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                   checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                           // Save to shared preferences
                           SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("arquivoPreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
                           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                           editor.putString("frase", frasesR[position]);
                           editor.commit();
                       }
                   });
                   checkBox.setText("Marcar como Favorito?");
                   // Recuperar dados
                   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(ARQUIVO_PREFERENCIA, MODE_PRIVATE);
                   if (sharedPreferences.contains("frase"))
                   {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(FraseAutorFrase.this, Favoritos.class);
                   }
```

ACTIVITY FAVORITOS

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("arquivoPreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String fraseR = sharedPreferences.getString("frase","Não Existem Favoritos!");
            // CRIANDO O ARRAY
            final String[] frasesFavoritoArray =
                    {
                            fraseR
                    };
            // UTILIZANDO O ADPTADOR PARA RECEBER O LISTVIEW
            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (
                            // Primeiro Parametro do Array Adpater é o Context
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            // Segundo Parametro do Array Adpater é o Layout
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            // Terceiro Parametro do Array Adapter é indicar o nome do Array para exibição
                            frasesFavoritoArray
                    );
            lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os valores salvos em SharedPreferences funcionam como um par "Chave-Valor". Para guardar vários valores, tem que usar chaves distintas. No seu caso, você está usando a mesma chave "frases" para toda a lista. Você pode fazer algo assim no seu código:

```
editor.putString("frase" + position, frasesR[position]);
```

Ele vai salvar os dados nas chaves "frase1", "frase2", etc. Depois você tem que adaptar o código que lê essas chaves.

Particulamente não é uma boa prática usar SharedPreferences pra guardar muitos dados, especialmente se os dados da sua lista forem dinâmicos, pois os dados guardados podem não corresponder ao momento em que eles foram salvos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Márcio.
Qual seria a maneira mais fácil para ler essas informações da "frase" + position?

Comment: Como eu disse, e lendo melhor o seu código, armazenar o que você quer em SharedPreferences não é muito bom, aliás vai dar até bastante trabalho de implementar. O ideal seria realmente usar banco de dados.

Comment: Se ainda quiser insistir com SharedPreferences, dá uma olhada nessa resposta, acho que vai te atender: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089411/how-to-get-all-keys-of-sharedpreferences-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Obrigado, Márcio.
Estou usando o SharedPreference mais por limitação de conhecimento em banco de dados, sei que o ideal seria usar o Sqlite.
Mais uma vez, Obrigado!!!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse curso, é muito bom. Aprendi com ele: https://br.udacity.com/course/android-basics-data-storage--ud845/

Comment: Valeu, Márcio.
Muito Obrigado, vou fazer esse curso, estou precisando.
Abraço!